# find number and add and operation character (java, knime)

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, knime

I am working on knime with a string replacer node and have to add an mathematical operation sign (multiplication, '*') behind a digit number (within a string cell). I find the numbers with the (java-based) regular expression

```
((?:\d+\.)?\d+ )
```

I tried to add the multiplication operation by adding the replacement text

```
((?:\d+\.)?\d+)\*
```

But the replacement now creates something like:

to be replaced:

```
1.456 substance
```

actually replaced by:

```
((?:\d+\.)?\d+)\*substance
```

But needed is:

```
1.456*substance
```

How can I modify the replacement text to get the needed output or what is the proper approach?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you meant to use a backreference `$1` in the replacement text. Something like `$1*substance`?

Comment: @Jongware: There is no actual code. It is a string-replace-node within knime which serves for the java code in the background. (sorry, I am really novice). Compare it with a find&replace e.g. within notepad.

Comment: @Rockbar why not `(\d*\.\d*)`? you can check the sample http://www.regexr.com/3bvkf

Comment: @kucing: I get an "Illegal group reference" using the replacement `$&*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you *search* for the text, you are using a *regular expression pattern*, and when replacing, you need a *replacement string*. The replacement string cannot contain the patterns, but it can contain back-references to the captured groups (numbered or named ones).

In Java, back-references are referenced to with `$`+`number` notation.

So, using `((?:\d+\.)?\d+)\s` regex, and a `$1*` replacement string, you can get what you need: `1.456*substance`.

See your [updated regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uV0rJ7/2).

Note that to match float values, you may consider using `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s` or `(\d*\.?\d+)\s` regex patterns. For a complex pattern to match all kinds of float numbers, see [*Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) at regular-expressions.info.

Comment: "Back-reference" is what I was looking for. Your code is exactly the solution. Thank you very much!